# Asynchronous div

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, asynchronous, widget

I have the following code in my Java EE application (JSP file, called from Servlet.java):

```
    <div class="drop">               
           <c:forEach var="widget" items="${widgets}">
              <div class="drag">
                 <p><h2>Widget</h2></p>
                 // WIDGET GRAPHIC REPRESENTATION
              </div>
           </c:forEach>
     </div>
     <input class="add" type="image" src="image.jpg">
```

What I want is loading and displaying the JSP file in the browser, and AFTER that, loading the widgets. The ideal situation would show a loading icon as long as a widget isn't loaded. How can I implement such an asynchronous solution? Could someone explain and/or give a small demo?

Comment: I think jquery's `load` event will be helpful

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: It looks like you asked something similar few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13235938/980472 Did you try what was suggested to you?

Comment: I did, but it was not exactly what I was looking for. As I already ticked it as solved, I created a new/clearer thread. Would be a bit weird if I asked something that I already knew, don't you think?:p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you, I am not sure

```
//use id of div(that contains the widgets) that 
//you want to hide before all widget are shown
$('#my_div_id')
    .hide()  // hide it initially and then use load event handler
    .load(function() {
        $(this).show();//display/show the div when load completes
    })
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your example! If I would use the 'drag' div of my example, does this mean that the code of the widget (At the moment 'WIDGET GRAPHIC REPRESENTATION), would be placed right above the line '$(this).show()'?

Comment: Yes try this example. And this is a jquery code you just need to keep your code that you have posted in your question as it is and in your head tag write two script tags one that imports jquery in your jsp and the other one that has the code that I have mentioned in my answer. Just look for a basic jquery tutorial for this.